# Transformar formato de data DD/MM/AA em MM/DD/AA em Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

O script lê a data de um .txt no formato DD/MM/AA, e preciso convertê-la para o formato MM/DD/AA com Bash, Sed ou AWK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em bash, existe algo chamado "parameter expansion" que consiste em manipular os argumentos. Sabendo disso, recomendo que evite usar `sed` e/ou `awk` em pipelines. Pois, devido cada pipeline gerar um processo, isso pode deixar seu código mais lento.

Utilizar do "parameter expansion" pode ser meio confuso no inicio, mas é uma bom truque! Veja:

```
$ set -- "31/12/1970"
$ echo "${1:3:3}${1:0:3}${1:6:4}"
12/31/1970
```

A sintaxe é simples: `${variável:offset:tamanho}`.
Neste caso, deixei o `"31/12/1970"` como um parâmetro `$1` e fui formatando cada informação apenas aproveitando cada "offset" que é a localização dos caracteres -, já o tamanho, refere-se a quantidade de caracteres que será mostrado à partir do offset que você definiu. Ou seja:

```
$ set -- "Edition 3"
$ echo "${1:8:1}rd ${1:0:7}"
3rd Edition
```

Outra dica para deixar mais legível, tu pode usar como array. Assim você tem uma "referencia" do que está tratando:

```
$ set -- "31/12/1970"
$ txt=("${1}")
$ echo "${txt[0]:3:3}${txt[0]:0:2}${txt[0]:5:5}"
12/31/1970
```

ps: Certifique de que estejam com aspas duplas, caso você coloque uma sintaxe do tipo: $variavel. Pode te dar algumas confusões se essa `$variavel` estiver vazia. Então, para evitar, basta usar deste jeito: "$variavel".

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de descobrir como.

É possível fazer utilizando AWK da seguinte maneira:

```
data=`echo $data | awk -F/ '{ print $2"/"$1"/"$3 }'`
```

Isso é bem útil para se obter a diferença entre duas datas.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira diferente de se fazer é usando o `sed`:

```
echo "31/12/1970" | sed -r 's/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)/\2\/\1\/\3/g'
```